# Derive value based on previous row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to derive new column "final".. The value of column is derived by referring to the previous value within a group. Within my data coA, colB, colC, colD forms a group and within this group the only value that will change is colE.

## Create SparkSession

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 1, 10, 0.1),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 2, 10, 0.2),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 3, 10, 0.3),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 4, 10, 0.1),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 5, 10, 0.2),
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["colA", "colB", "colC", "colD", "colE", "value", "pred"])

# Show DataFrame
df.show()

# Output data
output = [
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 1, 10, 0.1, 1),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 2, 10, 0.2, 0.2),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 3, 10, 0.3, 0.06),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 4, 10, 0.1, 0.006),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 5, 10, 0.2, 0.0012),
]

# Create DataFrame
output_df = spark.createDataFrame(output, ["colA", "colB", "colC", "colD", "colE", "value", "pred", "final"])
```

"Final" column is derived as follows:
For the first instance within the group, value is equal to value * pred. The value for ths remaining instance within the group will be: Final (from previous row) * pred.

My current logic is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
window_spec = Window.partition('colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD').orderBy('colE')
# This will derive value for first row within each group
a1 = input_df.withColumn('final', when(lag('colE').over(window_spec).isNull(), col('pred')*col('value')
a1 = a1.withColumn('final', when(col('final').isNotNull(), col('final'))
                    .otherwise(lag(col('final')).over(window_spec) * col('pred'))))
```

However, using the above logic, it only generate value for the first two row within each group.

```
# Output data
incorrect_output = [
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 1, 10, 0.1, 1),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 2, 10, 0.2, 0.2),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 3, 10, 0.3, null),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 4, 10, 0.1, null),
    ("A", "2003-03-01", 1, 11, 5, 10, 0.2, null),
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
    df
    .withColumn("first_value", f.first("value").over(Window.partitionBy("colA", "colB", "colC", "colD").orderBy("colE")))
    .withColumn("preds", f.collect_list("pred").over(Window.partitionBy("colA", "colB", "colC", "colD").orderBy("colE")))
    .select(
        df['*'],
        (f.col('first_value') * f.expr('aggregate(preds, cast(1 as DOUBLE), (acc, x) -> acc * x)')).cast(FloatType()).alias('Final')
    )
)
```

And the output is:

```
+----+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+------+                              
|colA|      colB|colC|colD|colE|value|pred| Final|
+----+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+------+
|   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   1|   10| 0.1|   1.0|
|   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   2|   10| 0.2|   0.2|
|   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   3|   10| 0.3|  0.06|
|   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   4|   10| 0.1| 0.006|
|   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   5|   10| 0.2|0.0012|
+----+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems 'aggregate' functionality is available in version 3.1. Unfortunately, my work system does have version 3.1. Is there any alternative solution you can guide to?

Comment: `aggregate` built-in function has been available since version 2.4. Check out this document https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate

Comment: Certainly, I am using an older version of PySpark :( ..

Answer (score 1):

##### Mathematical approach

```
f1 = v1 * p1
f2 = f1 * p2 = v1 * p1 * p2
f3 = f2 * p3 = v1 * p1 * p2 * p3
...
fn = fn-1 * pn = v1 * (p1 * p2 * ... * pn)
```

where:

```
pn represents the prediction value at the nth row.
fn represents the final value at the nth row.
v1 represents the value of the first row.
```

As you can see from the above calculation there is a pattern. v1 is constant for the calculation of f1, f2, .. fn, this means we can calculate the cumulative product of predictions then multiply that by the first value i.e `v1` within the group to get the result

```
W = Window.partitionBy('colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD').orderBy('colE')

v1 = F.first('value').over(W)
pn = F.product('pred').over(W)
result = df.withColumn('final', v1 * pn)
```

Result

```
result.show()

# +----+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+--------------------+
# |colA|      colB|colC|colD|colE|value|pred|               final|
# +----+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+--------------------+
# |   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   1|   10| 0.1|                 1.0|
# |   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   2|   10| 0.2| 0.20000000000000004|
# |   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   3|   10| 0.3| 0.06000000000000001|
# |   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   4|   10| 0.1|0.006000000000000002|
# |   A|2003-03-01|   1|  11|   5|   10| 0.2|0.001200000000000...|
# +----+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Certainly clever idea of converting mathematical notion into code! For now, I am using this approach but would eventually switch to the one suggested by ARCrow.